# ReCaptcha v3 always has a score of 0.1 points. In chrome secret mode

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, web, browser, recaptcha-v3

I recently added reCaptcha v3 to my site. with this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-recaptcha-v3)
It is React/Next.js/JavaScript project.

It works. When I tested it, it was 0.9 points. My colleague's script is 0.7 points.

It looks like pretty Good.

But, When I use Chrome Secret mode, I always get 0.1 point.

It is bug? or function ??

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert in this area. All I can do is make a guess.

ReCaptcha works by many different criterions. ReCaptcha collects information about users actions. But if user does not have any earlier actions to prove humane behavior ReCaptcha will automatically set lower score.

You have high score because you probably have visited sites that use ReCaptcha v3. You don't have high score in Incognito mode as every Incognito session is unique.

This is what Chrome says when you open new tab in Incognito mode:

```
Chrome won’t save the following information:
- Your browsing history
- Cookies and site data
- Information entered in forms
```

Comment: thank you for your answer :)

you said, "if user does not have any earlier actions to prove humane behavior ReCaptcha will automatically set lower score."

It is officially information about reCaptcha ? could i see that information in official document ?

Comment: @mononomo this is quoted from ReCaptcha v3 documentation

"The score is based on interactions with your site and enables you to take an appropriate action for your site."

When your site is used in Incognito mode ReCaptcha does not have any information about users previous actions.